# CREATE LOGIN from a trigger (User does not have permission to perform this action)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Using SQL 2019.

I need to create a LOGIN on SQL every time the value in column  becomes true.
This change is made via SP since user running it don't have enough privileges to update.

For this I create a trigger that detects if the column value changes and if is "true" will EXEC, however I'm getting a return message "User does not have permission to perform this action" and I try several workarounds to escalate privileges:

- Created trigger WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
- Create an SP WITH ONER and call to from trigger

This is the piece of code that always return the permission error: (obviously the variables used in the example were declared and values associated.

```
SET @SQL = 'USE [master];
            CREATE LOGIN [' + @email + '] WITH PASSWORD=N''Welcome2GETS''
                                             , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[hsatdb]
                                             , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
                                             , CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF
                                             , CHECK_POLICY=OFF;'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Doesn't matter if is inside of trigger or insideSP the error is the same

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) and a terrible idea; it's also wide open to injection (no, `'[' + @SomeVariable + ']'` is ***not*** injection safe). Why do you *want* to do this in the first place?

Comment: That doesn't explain anything though. I suggest you completely rethink what you do here. The fact you want to dynamically create `LOGIN`s based on a `INSERT` into a table, all with the same password (which is hard coded into the query ) is a severe flaw. Add the injection issue (which is a huge problem) and you just have a security hole the size of the moon just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: Sorry, I had internet issues and was cut out
I have 2 webs application consuming data from same DB.
One is Tech and other users (internal web apps)
Both uses SQL authentication to verify user (instead of a user for web), this way we can log which user is operating and where
On table "contacts" there is a column  "webaccess" - the tech webapp is the only capable to update this value true/false via SP. I need when the value change to true a trigger creates the new login, to allow the user to login.
I don't want to give access to tech run SLQ and much less increase the tech roles/privileges)

Comment: The login is created with minimum privileges, and the webapp will force the password to be changed on the first login, also the password will be generated randomly and will be pushed by e-mail, for the example I have not used the peace of code yet, but is ready in SLQ to generate the password and the web app will send by e-mail

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an internal authentication method, and then logging what people do; that have nothing to do with giving each person a their own `LOGIN`.

Comment: What is SLQ? My Google-Fu leads me to a website called "SLQSkills"; what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: "I need to create a LOGIN on SQL every time the value in column becomes true." - NO, you don't!

Comment: SLQ was typo, already fixed to SQL 2019 (SQL server 2019) to be more exact.
There are several reasons for wanting the login on SQL and a process that is already implemented and will not change shortly. 
Any idea how to resolve the privilege issue ( I try to run SP with OWNER, SETUSER, etc … nothing worked !!!)

Comment: @MitchWheat, we can debate if needed or if there are better ways to do it, but until a better option that suits my needs is presented … YES, I do. 
I came here looking for help resolving my issue, if you have better ideias how to turn around, I’m happy to hear and test, not really needing a lesson on what I don’t need.
Thanks

Comment: Suggest you read Erland's discussion of [permission packaging](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) which might work. And as already noted, your entire organization needs some serious education of how to implement security properly and defensively in public-facing applications. You also need some help designing application "eco-systems" that do not require this type of security risk and elevation" in order to function. Giving a login to anyone in the public is a dangerous practice.

Comment: At least use [QUOTENME(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your parameter.  Parameter-cleaning isn't the best solution, but It's probably the best security you can get for this case.

Comment: And people change their email accounts all the time - consider if your system can support that and can "cleanse" itself of old email addresses.

Comment: Also, the problem that you are running into is twofold.  First, `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is effectively acting as an `EXECUTE AS USER ...`, *which only transfers database-level permissions*.  However, the ability to create new LOGINs is a *server-level* permission.  And secondly, your dynamic SQL (`EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`) gets executed in a separate batch, which does not inherit your EXECUTE AS permissions.

Comment: Thank you @RBarryYoung and SMor, the code here is a sample to demonstrate where I’m beating against the wall, related to data maintenance, in this case the users are associated to RH, there are APIs in place and user is unique, hence doing it with trigger CREATE / DROP, if user is left or change e-mail the old is dropped.
USER is created with minimum privileges (only execute some store procedures - not all)
They login via web app and they never see the server endpoint and even if they do they can’t reach it without VPN. I really don’t want to share much more details around security … sorry

Comment: PauloL: No need.  My best advice is what @SMor said: read Erland's article on permission packaging.  I know that it is long and complicated, but so are the security issues for this kind of functionality.  The reason that no one is just giving an answer is because 1) the security implications are quite serious, and 2) the actual best answer depends on you current server, database and Login/User considerations and will require you to setup some additional things (like a special login. user or schema, generate a certificate, etc).  Erland's article covers what you need to know to figure this out.

Comment: Created trigger WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'

Comment: Thank you SMor and RBarryYoung, the information you provided help me finding a solution.